# Why GIT status is confusing when deleted a file and created a folder with same name?

Tags: git

I did this in a git repo. My git version is 2.9.0.

```
touch a
git add --all
git commit -m "file created"
rm a
mkdir a
cd a
touch b
git status
```

Now the status shows this, in the changes not staged for commit.

```
deleted: a
```

But it doesn't show anything for the fact that a new folder (named "a") is created and there is a new file (named "b") in it. Not even as untracked changes...

**I mean what about new file b, there is nothing in untracked file section or anything**

So the confusion is, if I remove a file and create a new folder/directory with the same name, git only shows that file is deleted, but **not the addition of the directory**.

However when I did `git add` and `commit`, I got my changes committed.

But why does `status` behave in such a way? Why is git confused when a file is deleted and a folder is created with the same name?

Comment: Doesn't it show folder 'a/' in `Untracked files:` part of status message?

Comment: no thats why .. not even acknowledge when i have a file inside that folder

Comment: What's git version?

Comment: git version is 2.9.0

Answer (score 3):

It's a minor bug in `git status`.  As [Arpit noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569297/1256452), you have to get `git status` to give you information about all untracked files, rather than letting it attempt to summarize directories ("folders").  When it does the summary instead, it gets confused by the fact that there is an entry in the index for a file with the shortened version of the name:

```
$ mkdir rmtest; cd rmtest; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/torek/tmp/rmtest/.git/
$ echo for testing rm file replace with dir > README
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) c650ec0] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo create a as file > a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m 'add file a'
[master e33cff2] add file a
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
$ rm a
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/b
```

We are now in your state: there is an untracked file named `a/b`, while tracked *file* `a` has gone missing.  The tracked file `a` is *still in the index* so it *will* be in the next commit made.  The untracked file `a/b` is *not* in the index, so it *will not* be in the next commit made—it cannot be; the tracked file `a` is in the way.

Due to the minor bug, `git status` reports this as:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    a

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

However, `git status -uall` makes `git status` list the contents of directory `a` individually, rather than trying to summarize them as "there are one or more untracked files within a directory named `a`", so that we see:

```
$ git status -uall
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    a

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    a/b

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This happens because the summarized version uses the path `a`, which—as noted above—remains in the index.  If we force a new commit, we can see that the new commit contains the file `a`:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m recommit
[master d7cbb81] recommit
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD
100644 blob ada8d39a4e96a31a4c7f2301dbfc807fcfdac71c    README
100644 blob 739675cd3231d46a10d4b8f477cc1b35857758c1    a
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* d7cbb81 (HEAD -> master) recommit
* e33cff2 add file a
* c650ec0 initial
```

Normally, Git would print "a/" in the "untracked files" section, but because `a` *is* tracked (and as we just saw, still gets committed!), it *can't* report it there (because it's missing a special case that would take it temporarily out of the in-core cache to allow it to be reported).

Interestingly, the same issue shows up differently if you `git reset HEAD a`:

```
$ git reset HEAD a
Unstaged changes after reset:
T   a
```

Note that here, Git is reporting the issue as a file-type change (the file type has gone from "regular file" to "directory", and Git does not store directories, so this is also a bug).

If we replace directory `a` containing file `a/b` with plain symlink `a`, the status reports become correct, since Git *is* able to store symlinks and is not attempting to summarize anything:

```
$ rm -r a; ln -s foo a
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    typechange: a

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `rm` something in your repo use `git rm` so git will manage your change more efficiently.

Comment: yes thanks , but for this question i expect why git is behaving this way , so that i take care next time

Answer (score 0):

> deleted: a

Git shows this message as you made Git notice about it running command:

```
git add -all
```

> but it doesnt show anything for the fact that new folder(named a) is
>   created and there is a new file(named b) in it.

Because you didn't add the file neither the folder to make Git track it.

**Edit:**

> yes but it is not showing file b in untracked section , thats what the
>   question is about

As you created a file in a folder which itself is untracked, you have to get the status using [`--untracked-files\[=<mode>\]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status--ultmodegt), as follows:

```
git status -uall
```

Comment: yes but git shows untracked files right, file b is nowhere shown in git status

Comment: you have to do `git add b` before running the `git status`, to make Git list the file.

Comment: no by default it shows new files in untracked section right?

Comment: yes, with with red color if you are checking it in Git Bash.

Comment: yes but it is not showing file b in untracked section , thats what the question is about

Comment: yes thanks a lot , but do you have any idea why it is not showing that file *b* by default

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you have "created a file in a folder which itself is untracked"

Comment: This is wrong. You don't have to add a folder to track files in it as long as the folder is in an tracked folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to force the update of untracked files but I don't know why git is behaving bad in first place :

```
git update-index --untracked-cache
```

Comment: thanks a lot..  but i seek explaination to behaviour in this question